# Argument `id`: Invalid value provided. Expected Int, provided String. Next.js Prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

i have a dynamic route to which i wanna pass an "id" to get the post.
here is my function.

```
 export async function getUserById(id){

  const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where:{
        id
    }
  })
}
```

the problem is when i call this function and pass an Int as id, it gives me the above error.
here is the dynamic route function.

```
const page = async ({params}) => {
  const id = parseInt(params.postId)
  const {post} = await getUserById(id)
  console.log(post)
  return (
    <div>
      dynamic goes here 
    </div>
  )
}
```

prisma schema and the folder structure..

```
model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  password String
  name  String?
}

model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String
  date String
  authorEmail String
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS08e.png)

i have tried functions like parseInt, Number but it didnt helped. please let me know whats wrong.

Comment: Can you show your prisma schema and a screenshot of your files structure?

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because when you send a number on a URL it comes like 'String'. To fix this you can try just to convert Str to Number.

Fixing it:

```
const page = async ({params}) => {
  const id = **Number(params.postId)**
  const {post} = await getUserById(id)
  console.log(post)
  return (
    <div>
      dynamic goes here 
    </div>
  )
}
```

I just change method ParseInt to Number...This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same error `Argument 'id': Invalid value provided. Expected String, provided Object.` when i used `const id = params;` and it got resolved when i changed my code to `const {id} = params;`

and you have `const id = parseInt(params.postId)` try changing it to `const {id}= parseInt(params.postId)` hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `parseInt` method parses a value as a string and returns the first integer

```js
export async function getUserById(id) {
  const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where:{
        id: **parseInt(id)**,
    }
  })
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this way.

```
import { title } from "@/components/primitives";
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import moment from 'moment'
import { Card, Image } from "@nextui-org/react";
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

// export default async function DetailPage(id: string) {
//     const a = Number(id)
export default async function DetailPage({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const a = params.id
  const b = parseInt(a)
  const movie = await prisma.movies.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: b,
    },
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {
        // allUsers.map(({ id, name, image, director, writer, actor, time, stars, online_date }) => (
        <div key={movie.id} >
          <div className="flex justify-start m-2">
            <div className="m-4">
              <h1 className={title()}>{movie.name}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex ">
            <div className="mr-4">
              <Card
                className="border-none"
              >
                <Image
                  alt="NextUI hero Image"
                  src={movie.image}
                  width={320}
                  height={480}
                  sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw,
                  (max-width: 1280px) 50vw,
                  (max-width: 1536px) 33vw,
                  25vw"
                />
              </Card>

            </div>
            <div>
              <p>导演：{movie.director}</p>
              <p>编剧：{movie.writer}</p>
              <p>主演：{movie.actor}</p>
              <p>上映日期：{moment(movie.online_date).format('yyyy-MM-DD')}</p>
              <p>片长：{movie.time}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        // ))
      }
    </div>

  );
}
```